# How do you achieve load balancing between n servers with i requests?

Tags: transactions, request, distributed-computing

> Describe how in the general case of n servers, each capable of serving s requests per second, you would allocate x requests from the queue to achieve load balancing. State any assumptions you make.

I am trying to give a reasonable answer to this problem. I was thinking that the simplest way to do it would be to allocate requests proportionally given the number of requests each server can process per second. If we have A (18/s), B(26/s) and C(56/s), my answer would be to pass 18 to A, 26 to B and 56 to C. In this way we would be able to process 100 requests per second. I was wondering if my reasoning was making any sense. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good to me. You can test it by moving a single request from any machine to any other, recalculate the time taken and verify that the total time taken will be slower than it was before. I think you'll find that any attempt to move a request will slow things down.

Comment: Is there any general formula or this can have several different interpretations?

Comment: I don't know of any general formula, but for static load balancing for throughput only it would just plain make sense to distribute requests proportional to the relative speed of the machines. If you're optimizing for something else, like for example average latency, things may look quite different.